# react datepicker default start date

Tags: reactjs, daterangepicker

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const loadAndSetData = async () => {
      setLoading(true);

      const startDate = moment()
        .startOf('day')
        .subtract(30, 'days');

      const endDate = moment().endOf('day');

      formRef.current.setFieldsValue({
        rangePicker: [startDate, endDate],
      });

      setLoading(false);
    };

  }, []);
```

Hi here is my code. I want to set start date as the first day of the previous month. I mean if today is 02.10.2021 start day should be 01.09.2021. How can i do that any idea?

Comment: *I mean if today is 02.10.2021 start day should be 01.09.2021.* You mean `01.10.2021` right?

Comment: No it should be 01.09.2021 like one month ago but first day of the month..

Comment: You should edit your question. I think it gives the wrong idea

Comment: Thanks for your comment :) I edited it. I'm kinda new so i think i couldn't explane myself very well.

Comment: No issues. Did my answer solve your problem?

Comment: Yes it did! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`subtract()`](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/03-manipulating/02-subtract/) and [`startOf()`](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/03-manipulating/03-start-of/) method to get this done.

```
const startDate = moment().subtract(1,'M').startOf('month');
        console.log(startDate.toString());
```